# Result from second query needs to be joined with each respective row of first query in json output

Tags: php, mysql, json

The problem is our result from second query needs to be joined with each respective row of 1st query. Image of actual result and how we need it is shown in the end

My **first query** selects data from a table by passing the USERNAME like this: `FROM admtask T WHERE  NVL(T.SNO,0) > ".$dxsno."  AND UPPER(T.PRIMARY)='".$dxusr."'` .

Note we know the sno number as well.

**Second query** - we want to count(*) from another table by passing the `sno` number using below query and fetch result of this query along with each row of above query which is not happening -

`$st1="select count(*) as SNO  from tasktag where sno='".$newsno."' and NVL(ISREAD,'N')='N' ";`

My entire query:

```
$stmt1="select  T.LATEST_ACTIVITY_NO, T.ISREAD, T.STATUS , T.SNO, T.ENTUSR, T.PRIMARY , T.ENTDT , T.DEADLINE_DT, T.REPORT_TO,ltrim(rtrim(TRANSLATE(CONVERT(T.TASKDESC,'US7ASCII') , '\n,\t',' ') )) TASKDESC,
    T.PRIORITY, T.HIGHLIGHT 
    FROM admtask T WHERE  
    NVL(T.SNO,0) > ".$dxsno."  AND UPPER(T.PRIMARY)='".$dxusr."'  ORDER BY   T.STATUS, T.LATEST_ACTIVITY_NO DESC";

    $result=oci_parse($conn,$stmt1);
    $ex2=oci_execute($result);
    $newsno=0;

    while ($row1=oci_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

                    $newsno=$row1["SNO"];

                    $st1="select count(*) as SNO  from tasktag where sno='".$newsno."' and NVL(ISREAD,'N')='N' ";
                    $rs1=oci_parse($conn,$st1);
                    $ex1=oci_execute($rs1);

                    while ($r1=oci_fetch_assoc($rs1))
                    {
                      $cnt = $r1["SNO"];
                    }
                    $c1=$cnt;
                    echo "cnt=".$cnt;   
    $emparray[] = $row1;
```

Actual representation of how data is coming and how we need it:

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: can you please suggest me the answer as per my query